# Empty notification panel

Tags: windows-10-mobile, notifications, nokia-lumia-535, action-center

I can't have my messages and calls in notification panel all of sudden. I have upgraded to Windows 10 Mobile but after upgrading,everything was just fine. I could see them in notification panel but from now on I am unable to have any messages and WhatsApp notifications in the notification panel. When a message arrives it shows a banner and I can read or respond to the message right from the banner but after banner disappears and I slide down the notification panel there's nothing. Although there's a "Clear all" option which is absolutely useless as I have nothing notification panel.

[image]
[image]

My phone's specifications are here if relevant.

[image]

Some other points:

- All settings are intact
- Problem continues whether Battery saver mode is on or not.
- Notification panel shows some notification when I put it on charging otherwise it remains empty.

Comment: If you can't resolve your problem you need to do factory(hard) reset.

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons.

- Battery-Saver on? The battery-saver prevents apps to load/work in the background.
- Notifications are only showed when locked. One thing to try (I can't comment to post since I am new): Lock your screen, let some notifications come in and see if there is something on the notification panel.

"Wrong" notification settings? These settings are found in Settings -> System -> Notifications & Actions (I am using a dutch translated phone, so don't blame me if it's not correct). Turn the first (View Notifications in panel when phone is locked (or related)) option on (or turn everything on). You will be fine then.

Hope it helps!

*Check your app settings aswell.

Comment: I had tried and settings are Ok as I think............Moreover I also have updated my question. Please have a review on it. +1 for help

Comment: Are all settings on in the settings page? Including app settings?

Comment: Yup everything alright and I was getting notifications for same settings previously but now I can't

Answer (score 2):

That's an bug in the OS build 10.0.14393.693. Restarting your device should make your notifications appear again, but after that, if you restart again, notifications are gone.

Do report this problem in the Feedback Hub (Better, give an upvote to existing problems). I had the same problem, so I have also. As soon as the next update to the OS arrives, install it, and hopefully the bug will be removed.

Hope this helps. If it did, give me an upvote.

Comment: I tried and yes you're right. This does happen some of the times but as I stated sometimes notifications appear when the phone is put on charge. Well if it is a bug, then I hope Microsoft won't ignore it. +1 for help :)